# Elo rating system looking for good resource

Tags: algorithm, rating

Anyone can link good article about ELO Rating system algorithm? How it works and why there is a constant? Also what are score and expected Score?

Comment: You might enjoy this article on [TrueSkill](http://www.moserware.com/2010/03/computing-your-skill.html), Microsoft's improvement over Elo. The article goes into some detail about Elo as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) is a good starting point.

In **Elo** formula you have *two* constants:

- denominator (400),
- K-factor (usually 10 to 40).

The base formula is simple:

[image: R_{A}^{\prime }=R_{A}+K(S_{A}-E_{A}).]

Updated Elo points are previous points corrected by the *performance*, where S_A is the *score* (three values: 1 for win, 0.5 for draw, 0 for loss) and E_A is the *expected score* (that is "*his probability of winning plus half his probability of drawing*"),

[image: E_{A}={\frac {1}{1+10^{(R_{B}-R_{A})/400}}}.]

Here's a [comparison](https://rankade.com/ree#ranking-system-comparison) between Elo and some post-Elo rating systems.